# Convert native sql query to JPA query

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I need help to perform the following SQL query in a JPA query, or some way to get the last record in Oracle with JPA.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM OAJ_COMITE ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: Rows in a table have no inherent ordering. Any apparent order you think you're seeing is an artifact of data storage which the database is free to change at any time. `ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC` just means you'll get the unordered results backwards. So what's the point? You could as easily say `ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC`, take the first row returned, and the results would be equally valid.

Comment: @BobJarvis, sort by ROWNUM only couldn't be used at all - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm) says "Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.", so your internal query does not have any sence.

So if you want to get last line **by some criteria**, you should use form like
`select * from table order by field desc fetch first row only`, where `field desc` is your sort parameters.

BTW, I'm not sure it's possible to convert query like this to JPA, because there are used Oracle-specific constructions. So you'll need to use 'native query', not JPA.